# Question on DB design approaches in Java

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee

I have data in a DB that have hierarchical relationship (could be represented as a tree).
Right now, whenever a request comes in the server, a recursive query is done in the DB to create an in-memory list (which is a branch of the tree, from leaf to root that actually exists) and
do processing using that list.
This is not very efficient, but at least it works for now, and has the advantage that if the DB is changed, the changes gets immediately noticed.
Anyway, I want to improve it and looking for a pattern to:
1)Not to have to access the DB all the time
2)If a change is done in the DB, it gets **immediatelly** reflected
3)It can be used in all places of the server.
Is there a standard design pattern commonly used for cases like this? Or just have a data structure maintained by a backend thread and on any update in the DB, reload everything in the data structure?

Thank you

Comment: Excuse me, I don't get the point. Are you asking for representation of hierarchy suitable for processing (not build structure in memory every time)?

Comment: The project is an old project that is using a custom framework to access the DB (it is older than Hibernate and it has not been refactored to use a newer framework).So I am looking for a custom solution to cache the actual data in memory and update them when needed.

Comment: I totally agree with @iruediger. It sounds you need Caching that get updated on insert/update/delete in the Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a thread you could use a caching solution. The result of the query would be cached and returned on every request, if any of the tables in the query are modified you invalidate the cache, wait until the next request to retrieve the new values and load them on the cache. This solution meets requisites 1 and 2. What do you mean by "It can be used in all places of the server"?

If you are using Hibernate, this can be easily done with the [second level cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache), the caveat is that you must guarantee that only your application changes the database (no external processes).

If you are not using Hibernate, you can roll your own solution with [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/). You would need to change the method that returns the structure to check the cache before querying the DB. Methods that make changes to the tables involved, would have to modified to invalidate the cache.

Ehcache also has [integration with Spring](http://ehcache.org/recipes/spring-annotations.html), but I've never tried it.

Comment: IMHO, Spring does not have caching solution. But they have interface with EHCache, and I heard it's good.

Comment: @Rudy You are right, it is not a caching solution. I've corrected my post.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much details which ORM tool you use, but in Hibernate, this is doable by declaring a list of children. Below is taken from the production code:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="YourTreeClass" table="tree_table" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
   ...other properties...

      <list name="children" cascade="save-update" inverse="false" >
         <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
         <key column="parent_id"/>
         <one-to-many class="YourTreeClass" />
      </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

No need for hacky background threads - on node update, Hibernate takes care and invalidates relevant cached entries.

Comment: The project is an old project that is using a custom framework to access the DB (it is older than Hibernate and it has not been refactored to use a newer framework).So I am looking for a custom solution

Comment: Doh! You should have said that in the very beginning.